# Application won't work properly when installed from Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I am facing a very strange problem in my app. I use a notification to bring my app from background to foreground via a Service. My problem is that when I install the apk file from pc (via Eclipse or by copying the apk to my device), the notification works perfectly. When I install my app from the Play Store (same apk), and the user taps the notification, it starts a new instance of `EntryScreen` and don't work as launcher icon! Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in Advance!

The Service code:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Intent intentForeground = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EntryScreen.class);

    intentForeground.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    intentForeground.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    PendingIntent pendint = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intentForeground, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.final_driver_notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle("...")
            .setContentText("...")
            .setContentIntent(pendint)
            .setTicker("...");

    Notification notif = mBuilder.build();

    int notID = 1;

    startForeground(notID, notif);


    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe is in the Manifest, you need to add launchMode in your activity that open with notification. For example if your activity is EntryScreen.class, see the code for the manifest.

```
<activity
            android:name=".EntryScreen"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

Comment: I tried that too and it didn't help.But if that is the problem why when i install the app from eclipse it works perfect and from Play Store not?

Comment: uhm.. that wear, try to use com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging library from Google Play service insted of gcm from jar

Comment: When i remove the gcm.jar how to extends the GCMBaseIntentService?

Comment: The new notification use gcm from google play service. This is an example :http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help!